# What's the optimal time for connection-time in nagios

Tags: monitoring, nagios

I'm monitoring mysql using nagios (using [check_mysql_health](http://labs.consol.de/lang/en/nagios/check_mysql_health/)) and I want to use connection-time - but I don'y quite know what are the times that I need to ask for.
So my question is - What is the optimal time for connection-time - for warning and critical notifications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would expect a general database access to be fast, maybe couple milliseconds (<10 ms) and 100 ms would be slow. On the other hand, if the database is on another server with poor connection, the times might be much larger.

One approach would be running the system for some time and checking the times that `check_mysql_health` reports. If your intent is to get a notification when something abnormal happens, you first have to measure what is normal and then adjust the limits accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Well, nagios is located on one server and mysql is on anther server - so I think I'll take your advice, I will simply test it for a while... thanks.